# How to use a dictionary to append values to a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

Trying to solve a leetcode problem right now and think I have an idea for a solution but need some help. I am given 2 lists: 1 is a list of values, and the other is the index value where I should place such values. Such as below:

```
nums = [1, 5, 3]
index = [0, 1, 2]
```

So, I would have to append number 1 at index 0, 5 at index 1, etc.

I have solved the problem with simple while loop but now I want to solve the problem with a dictionary, so I have made this so far:

```
 list2 = []

 ans = dict(zip(nums, index))
        
 list2.insert(someindex, somenumber)
```

My question is how I can access the data in the dictionary to finish my insert command. how can I replace the code at 'someindex' and 'somenumber' to represent the index and corresponding value stored in my dictionary? Is this possible?
Thanks for the help

Comment: The question is unclear. What are you really trying to achieve? Right now it seems you will just obtain `list2 = nums.copy()`. Are the indices always sorted? None missing? Solving this problem for unsorted indices should anyway be more efficient with a simple loop. Using a dictionary will just get you to have to loop a second time.

Comment: What is the actual leet code question?

Comment: hi. the problem is called create target array in the given order. maybe my idea for solution is unnecessary, but I wanted to know if it was possible because I tend to see the best solutions utilize dictionaries.

Comment: target_array = []
        for num, ind in zip(nums, index):
            target_array.insert(ind, num)
        return target_array

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? Is the dictionary the input to the program, or just an intermediate step? What should the dictionary contain, and why? What should the result be, and why? Why is the dictionary supposed to be helpful for solving the problem? What actually is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very convoluted way of doing things. (keep it simple. for loop is much better) but here are a few ways.

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0], sorted(ans.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])))


[x[0] for x in sorted(ans.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

Need sorted here because you never mentioned that indices list is sorted

Going one step back you do not need to create a dict. zip object would suffice

```
[x[0] for x in sorted(zip(nums, index), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

this would save unnecessary transformation to dict

Answer (score 0):

if that is the case, you could order your code as follow and get a list from the dictionary values you are building there, something like this might help you solve the issue, if I understood what you are trying to accomplish with this:

```
nums = [1, 5, 3]
index = [0, 1, 2]
list2 = list(dict(zip(index,nums)).values())
print(list2)
```

Comment: This does work, but it fails in the scenario that the same index is referred to more than 1 time, for example if mums was [1,5,3,7] and index was [0, 1, 2, 2], as the problem wants all values to be in the list. Thank you

Comment: Dictionaries do not support duplicate keys. If index if indeed the position that you want for the correspondent item in nums, we can't simply give the same index since it will overwrite its previous value. By running the code I provided with your example, it overwrites its previous value, as expected. Dunno why you'd like to have the same index for two separated items, the only way this can be done is by adding both items as a list in the given index for nums but that'd be another approach to validate if the index is the same as the previous to add its current value plus the new one as a list.

Comment: With that being said, the example you are providing with duplicated indexes should look like this: [1,5,[3,7]], but again, for that, we'd want to refactor the current code to validate the duplications first: Do you mind sharing the leetcode problem statement to have a more concise idea of what the outcome should look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
nums = [1, 5, 3]
index = [0, 1, 2]
ans = dict(zip(index, nums))
list2 = [0 for _ in range(len(ans))]

for index, value in ans.items():
    list2[index] = value
```

Note that you **must** instantiate `list2` the way described because you'll get index out of range exception otherwise.